# How to implement a list of Generic Interfaces

Tags: java, oop, generics, interface

Hello I'm working on some interesting code and a thought has crossed my mind.

Here is some simplified code:

```
public interface SomeInterFace<T>
{
    public List<T> doSomething();
}
```

Now, I got another interface which should extend this one for various Objects for instance

```
public interface OtherInterface extends SomeInterface<Integer>, 
SomeInterFace<String>, SomeInterface<Number>, ...
```

Is there a possiblity to write this "OtherInterface" in a manner where it implements "SomeInterface" with a list of objects?

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't possible with java generics.  you can't have multiple methods with the same name return the same generic type with a different parameter.  this is due to how generics are handled in java.

Comment: how about just `public interface OtherInterface extends SomeInterface<T>` ??

Comment: @PremGenError don't think thats compilable, im not sure if it is with some minor changes

Comment: @ZeDonDino it'd compile if you define the generic type `public <T> interface OtherInterface extends SomeInterface<T>`

Comment: Your right but this would mean if you implement interface "OtherInterface" with Object "A" (e.g. Integer) you would implement also "SomeInterface" with the same object. Not what I need tho

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to handle any type of type argument for `OtherInterface`, then as others have suggested, you can write:

```
public interface OtherInterface<T> extends SomeInterface<T>
```

However, if you need to implement `SomeInterface` only for a particular list of type arguments (say, `String` and `Number`), then you cannot do that.  At compile time, `SomeInterface<(anything)>` just becomes `SomeInterface` due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), and the casting is inserted for you after the compiler makes sure you aren't trying to do any unsafe casts (or you've told it not to check).  Therefore, you would be trying to write a class that looked something like this:

```
public interface OtherInterface extends SomeInterface, SomeInterface {
    public List doSomething();
    public List doSomething();
}
```

...which is invalid for obvious reasons!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ha.  The fastest keyboard in the Midwest, I suppose. :)

Comment: If you look at my question your answer doesn't help me at all since as I stated: "Your right but this would mean if you implement interface "OtherInterface" with Object "A" (e.g. Integer) you would implement also "SomeInterface" with the same object. Not what I need tho "

Comment: If you're not trying to accomplish one of the two cases I mentioned, then I'm not exactly sure what you're after.  Could you be more explicit?  You are indeed, in your question, trying to implement `SomeInterface` with the same object (`OtherInterface`).